# How can an incomplete type be used as a template parameter to vector here?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

TIL the following program is legal and whatnot:

```
#include <vector>

struct Bar;

struct Foo
{
    using BarVec = std::vector<Bar>::size_type;
};

struct Bar {};

int main()
{
   Foo f;
}
```

How? `Bar` is an incomplete type so the compiler has no way of knowing what `std::vector<Bar>` is, or that it contains a member `size_type`, or that the member `size_type` is a type.

The only explanation I can come up with is that any hypothetical specialisation would (presumably) have to already be in scope to cause `size_type` to take on a meaning different from that given in the "base" template definition, and `size_type` is not a dependent name (both factors contributing to the compiler's certainty).

What's the legal rationale here?

Comment: None of these directly (i.e. pointing to a specific section of the standard) answer your question, but they provide some insight [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329826/can-standard-container-templates-be-instantiated-with-incomplete-types), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620378/why-do-c-templates-let-me-circumvent-incomplete-types-forward-declarations), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770318/incomplete-types-in-template-code)

Comment: How did you learn that the program is legal and whatnot?  I was able to compile it, but if you have a more authoritative source we may be able to work from there.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Well, to be fair, nothing authoritive (that's what I'm looking for here), but [nobody here seems to have any problems or complaints](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31342839/560648). "Actually it's _not_ legal" with proof would be a perfectly valid answer here. :)

Comment: @DrewDormann this comes from my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31343136/4342498)

Comment: According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), it's legal.

Comment: The legal rationale is that this is UB by [res.on.functions]/2.5 pre-C++1z: "In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: [...] if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component."

Comment: In the more general case, the answer is that incompleteness doesn't matter; `Bar` is still just a single type, not a bazillion possible types. `void` is an incomplete type that cannot be completed; we instantiate templates over `void` all the time. The "later specialization" scenario is outlawed by assorted rules in the standard.

Comment: I didn't want to dominate the comments section here, so I gave this a few hours to simmer.  I believe that a *hypothetical specialisation* is irrelevant here, as it's [UB *not* to define that specialization before it would be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912689).  I think that reduces the question to "can `using BarVec = std::vector<X>::size_type;` be well-defined for an incomplete type`X`?"  I could *swear* that one of our regular, standard-quoting C++ hotshots answered that in the affirmative a few months ago, for type definitions that didn't require the definition of `X`.

Comment: I'm curious, would you consider a simpler example equivalent: ``template <class T> struct Foo { void qux(T t) { t.qux() } }; using baz = Foo<Bar>`` where Bar is incomplete as before. It seems like this should not compile, but it does.

Comment: @NirFriedman: Dunno, fix the three syntax errors then maybe :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think in practice this may work but from what I can tell this looks like undefined behavior. From the draft C++11 standard `17.6.4.8` *[res.on.functions]*:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> [...]
>
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component,
>     unless specifically allowed for that component.

Although *instantiating a template component* does not seem like a well-defined term.

I came to this via [LWG defect 611](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#611) which added:

> unless specifically allowed for the component.

to the end of the bullet above so it now reads:

> if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, **unless specifically allowed for the component.**

as an exception for `shared_ptr` since the above quote conflicted with this quote from `20.6.6.2` [util.smartptr.shared]:

> The template parameter T of shared_ptr may be an incomplete type.

Also see [N4371: Minimal incomplete type support for standard containers, revision 2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4371.html).

Comment: See updated version of 4371 which is [N4510](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html)