# class (or struct) self-reference by template

Tags: c++, class, language-lawyer, self-reference

Is the following legal?

```
template< typename T >
struct tree_node
   {
   T t;
   std::vector<tree_node> children;
   };
```

A comment to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15473485/86967) seems to suggest that it is not.

---

EDIT: This doesn't strike me as an "undefined behavior" type of scenario.  The intended semantics are unambiguous.  If it is an invalid usage of an incomplete type then it should be a compile-time error.

[In my tests](https://ideone.com/JPO782) this seems to work fine (I have used both [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) and [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) -- both with `-Wall -Werror -std=c++11`).

Is there something in the language definition (prior to C++17) that directly or indirectly specifies this as undefined behavior, or is it just *under-specified*?

---

Keep in mind that this is very similar, structurally, to something like the following:

```
typedef int T;
struct tree_node;

struct tree_node
   {
   T t;
   tree_node * children;
   }
```

Comment: Possible dupliucate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345193/how-can-an-incomplete-type-be-used-as-a-template-parameter-to-vector-here

Comment: The "exception for shared_ptr" cracks me up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31347287/86967

Comment: Worst-case scenario, you could use `shared_ptr<tree_node>` instead of just `tree_node`.

Comment: ...or maybe `shared_ptr<vector<tree_node>>`.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, as a result of [N4371](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4371.html) we have (from N4527, [vector.overview], will be in C++17):

> An incomplete type `T` may be used when instantiating vector if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness
>   requirements 17.6.3.5.1. `T` shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of
>   vector is referenced.

Prior to this, `vector` could not be constructed with an incomplete type (which `tree_node` is at that point), and that would be undefined behavior.

Comment: that's incredible. how do you do small object optimization with such a loose requirement ?

Comment: @v.oddou `std::vector` doesn't do a small buffer optimization.

Comment: It's not something we can tell for sure, "this implementation of std::vector" doesn't do it, sure. but implementation is not specified. if we start to put these weird phrasings in the spec, now the implementation becomes constrained to not do it, but by mistake rather than by explicit design.

Comment: @v.oddou Sure we can. `std::vector` has to support incomplete types and `swap` can't invalidate iterators.

Comment: yes but that's what I mean. It's not specifically said "small object optimization is prohibited" in the standard. It's implied from constraints set by unrelated phrasings. This seems like a bug.