# Incomplete type as tag type for templates

Tags: c++, templates

Incomplete types are generally not allowed at template instantiation, but does that hold even when the incomplete type is not explicitly used? gcc 5.1 and VS 2015 allow it, but I'm not sure. Example:

```
    template<typename T>
    struct B{
       // not using T 
    };

    struct tag1{};
    struct tag2; // incomplete
    using C1 = B<tag1>;
    using C2 = B<tag2>;
    using C3 = B<struct tag3>; // hmm...

    int main(){
        C1 c1;
        C2 c2;
        C3 c3;
    }
```

Bonus: what about `tag3` above?

***Edit:*** in response to the suggested duplicate, `std::vector` does in contrast to `B` make use of the type of the template argument. Have a look at the accepted answers: this is allowed but the question about `vector` is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an incomplete type be used as a template parameter to vector here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345193/how-can-an-incomplete-type-be-used-as-a-template-parameter-to-vector-here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use an incomplete type as a template type argument - provided that you never use that type argument in a context that requires a complete type. This is handy for when you want a template argument to distinguish two different class templates - but don't actually need it for anything else.

Since `B` never tries to do anything with `T` that requires it to be complete, all three instantiations of it (`C1`, `C2`, and `C3`) are perfectly valid.

Comment: Cool. That's what i hoped.

Comment: This is especially handy for the pimpl idiom with unique_ptr

Comment: @Claudiu Yes and no. I think the OP's question is specifically for incomplete types that never are used in the template, whereas with pimpl you declare it with an incomplete type, with the requirement that it becomes complete before any use.

Comment: Correct. This is for example to spawn multiple classes with the same functionality, but with different type. Such as `myfloatT<class velocityTag>` and `myfloatT<class distanceTag>`,