# No member named "XXX" in a simple CRTP case

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

Here I have a simple CRTP case:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <typename Impl>
class base
{
    constexpr static size_t impl_num = Impl::num;
};

template <typename Impl>
class deriv : public base<deriv<Impl>>
{
    friend class base<deriv<Impl>>;

    constexpr static size_t num = Impl::num_in;
};

class actual_impl
{
public:
    constexpr static size_t num_in = 10;
};

using my_type = deriv<actual_impl>;

int main()
{
    my_type a{};
}
```

This snippet compiles fine but when I change the base class to:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <typename Impl>
class base
{
    constexpr static std::make_index_sequence<Impl::num> idx{};
};

template <typename Impl>
class deriv : public base<deriv<Impl>>
{
    friend class base<deriv<Impl>>;

    constexpr static size_t num = Impl::num_in;
};

class actual_impl
{
public:
    constexpr static size_t num_in = 10;
};

using my_type = deriv<actual_impl>;

int main()
{
    my_type a{};
}
```

Clang complains that `error: no member named 'num' in 'deriv<actual_impl>'`. I'm just confused why the first case works but not the second one, what's the fundamental difference between these two since it seems to me that in both cases `Impl::num_in` are used in base class.

In general, is it possible for base class to use typedefs or constexprs from `Impl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental difference is the moment when you're trying to access the internals of the `Impl` class. `Impl` in `base<Impl>` is an incomplete type, and there are certain restrictions on what you can do with it.

In particular, you can't access `num` data member inside `base`, that's why the line

```
constexpr static std::make_index_sequence<Impl::num> idx{};
```

causes a compilation error. Note that to define the `base` class, a compiler has to know the value of `Impl::num` right at that moment.

In contrast to that, in your first example, `Impl::num` is used only to *initialize* a value of `impl_num`, which otherwise doesn't depend on `Impl::num`. Instantiation of that initialization happens later, at the point when `Impl` becomes a complete type. Hence, there is no error.

If you slightly change the definition,

```
template<typename Impl>
class base {
    constexpr static decltype(Impl::num) impl_num = Impl::num;
    // or 
    constexpr static auto impl_num = Impl::num;
}
```

and make `impl_num` *type* dependent on `Impl`, you'll get the same error by the same reason.

Adding indirection doesn't help, the following code also fails to compile:

```
template<typename Impl>
class base {
    constexpr static size_t impl_num = Impl::num;
    constexpr static std::make_index_sequence<impl_num> idx{};
};
```

> In general, is it possible for base class to use typedefs or constexprs from `Impl`?

It depends. You can use them only in contexts where instantiations happen when `Impl` is a complete type. For example,

```
template<typename Impl>
class base {
public:
    void foo() {
        decltype(Impl::num) impl_num = 0;
    }
};
```

is fine, but

```
template<typename Impl>
class base {
public:
    decltype(Impl::num) foo() { 
        return 0;
    }
};
```

is not.

The standard trick to avoid potential problems with incomplete types in CRTP is the introduction of a helper traits class:

```
// Just forward declarations
template<typename Impl> class deriv;
class actual_impl;

using my_type = deriv<actual_impl>;

template<class> struct traits;
template<> struct traits<my_type> {
    using num_type = std::size_t;
};

template <typename Impl>
class base {
public:
    typename traits<Impl>::num_type foo() {
        return 0;
    }
};

// Now actual definitions
// ...
```

Here, to access `traits<Impl>` internals, `Impl` doesn't have to be a complete type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, can you clarify why the compiler doesn't need a complete type in case of ```typename traits<Impl>::num_type``` ? Or is this a specific C++ topic that I can search online that I can figure this out myself?

Comment: @JundaLi Because `Impl` is only used to select a particular template specialization of `traits`, so the only thing that a compiler needs to know is a type name. Here is a [related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33399093).