# how to avoid CRTP "error: invalid use of incomplete type" for classes with all public static methods?

Tags: c++, enums, static-methods, crtp

the goal is several scoped enums (each in it own struct/class/namespace) with some associated utility functions.  I've used that pattern many times  and the  utility functions always include a toString() and fromString() function for human intelligible i/o.

However, this time I've got several different types of dimensions: Length, Time, Angle, ...
that I want to handle Unit's for so the naming pattern of these structs structs/classes/namespaces is Unit.  And these different classes are practically identical except each one has an enum of units specific to that dimension.

for the LengthUnit struct/class/namespace the enum is currently

```
enum type
{
    meters=0,
    kilometers,
    SIZE
};
```

obviously I could add centimeters, millimeters, micrometers, miles, feet, yards etc, but I don't need those right now

for the TimeUnit struct/class/namespace the enum is

```
enum type
{
    seconds=0,
    milliseconds,
    microseconds,
    nanoseconds,
    SIZE
};
```

for the AngleUnit struct/class/namespace the enum is

```
enum type
{
    degrees=0,
    radians,
    SIZE
};
```

each Unit class has 4 identically (across dimensions) named functions

```
static std::string toString(type unit); 
static type fromString(std::string unitString); 
static std::string toAbbreviation(type unit);
static type fromAbbreviation(std::string unitString);
```

the toString() and toAbbreviation() functions are specific to the Type because each contains a custom switch statement to convert from unit to string.

the fromString() and fromAbbreviation() function have a common implementation, they loop over the enum lists essentially a for(type unit=0; unit<SIZE; ++unit) (with some static_cast-ing) to compare the string to the one coming out of toString() or toAbbreviation() when it finds a match it breaks, if it doesn't find a match it returns SIZE, errors are thrown exceptions

and each unit has function whose name is specific to the type of dimension, for example
static double lengthInMeters(const type unit): //for unit=LengthUnit::meters this returns 1.0, for unit=LengthUnit::kilometers it returns 1000.0
static double timeInSeconds(const type unit);  //for unit=TimeUnit::seconds this returns 1.0, for unit=TimeUnit::milliseconds it returns 1e-3, etc.
static double angleInDegrees(const type unit);

to decrease boiler plate code (because the fromString() and fromAbbreviation() function have identical implementations across dimension types) I tried to template the common class and use the CRTP to do it, the relevant code you need to compile and reproduce the same error is

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>
#include <cstring>

class StringException : public std::exception
{
protected:
    const std::string m_message;
public:
    StringException(const std::string& message) : m_message(message) {};

    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return m_message.c_str();
    };
};

inline std::string toLower(std::string str)
{
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
    return str;
};

struct DimensionType
{
    enum type
    {
        Length=0,
        Time,
        Angle,
        SIZE
    };

    std::string toString(const type dimType=SIZE)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        switch(dimType)
        {
            case Length: return std::string("Length");
            case Time: return std::string("Time");
            case Angle: return std::string("Angle");
            case SIZE:
                oss << "SIZE=" << SIZE;
                return oss.str();
            default:
                oss << "DimensionType::toString():\n  "
                    << "We either encountered an invalid DimensionType value OR\n  "
                    << "DimensionType::toString() needs to be updated to handle a new DimensionType value\n";
                throw(StringException(oss.str()));
        }
    };

    type fromString(const std::string dimString)
    {
        for(type dimType=Length; dimType<SIZE; dimType=static_cast<type>(dimType+1))
        {
            try
            {
                if(dimString.compare(toString(dimType))==0)
                    return dimType;         
            }
            catch(std::exception& e)
            {
                std::ostringstream oss;
                oss << "DimensionType::fromString():\n  "
                    << e.what();
                throw(StringException(oss.str()));
            }
        }
        return SIZE;
    };
};

typedef DimensionType::type DimensionType_t;


template <class T>
class DimensionUnit 
{
public:
    static const std::string DimName;
    static const DimensionType_t DimType;

    static typename T::type fromString(std::string unitString)
    {
        unitString=toLower(unitString);
        for(typename T::type unit=static_cast<typename T::type>(0); unit<T::SIZE; unit=static_cast<typename T::type>(unit+1))
        {
            try
            {
                if(unitString.compare(typename T::toString(unit))==0)
                    return unit;                
            }
            catch(std::exception& e)
            {
                std::ostringstream oss;
                oss << DimName << "Unit::fromString():\n  "
                    << e.what();
                throw(StringException(oss.str()));
            }
        }
        return T::SIZE;
    };

    static typename T::type fromAbbreviation(std::string unitString)
    {
        unitString=toLower(unitString);
        for(typename T::type unit=static_cast<typename T::type>(0); unit<T::SIZE; unit=static_cast<typename T::type>(unit+1))
        {
            try
            {
                if(unitString.compare(typename T::toAbbreviation(unit))==0)
                    return unit;                
            }
            catch(std::exception& e)
            {
                std::ostringstream oss;
                oss << DimName << "Unit::fromAbbreviation():\n  "
                    << e.what();
                throw(StringException(oss.str()));
            }
        }
        return T::SIZE;
    };
};

class LengthUnit : public DimensionUnit<LengthUnit>
{
    public:
    enum type
    {
        meters=0,
        kilometers,
        SIZE
    };

    static double lengthInMeters(const type unit)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        switch(units)
        {
            case meters: return 1.0;
            case kilometers: return 1000.0;
            case SIZE:
                oss << "LengthUnit::lengthInMeters():\n  "
                    << "SIZE is not a LengthUnit value.  It is a count of defined LengthUnit values\n  "
                    << "that enables iteration/looping.\n";
                throw(StringException(oss.str()));
            default:
                oss << "LengthUnit::lengthInMeters():\n  "
                    << "We either encountered an invalid LengthUnit value OR\n  "
                    << "LengthUnit::lengthInMeters() needs to be updated to handle a new LengthUnit value\n";
                throw(StringException(oss.str()));
        }       
    };

    static std::string toString(const type unit=SIZE)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        switch(units)
        {
            case meters: return std::string("meters");
            case kilometers: return std::string("kilometers");
            case SIZE:
                oss << "SIZE=" << SIZE;
                return oss.str();
            default:
                oss << "LengthUnit::toString():\n  "
                    << "We either encountered an invalid LengthUnit value OR\n  "
                    << "LengthUnit::toString() needs to be updated to handle a new LengthUnit value\n";
                throw(StringException(oss.str()));
        }
    };

    static std::string toAbbreviation(const type unit=SIZE)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        switch(units)
        {
            case meters: return std::string("m");
            case kilometers: return std::string("km");
            case SIZE:
                oss << "SIZE=" << SIZE;
                return oss.str();
            default:
                oss << "LengthUnit::toAbbreviation():\n  "
                    << "We either encountered an invalid LengthUnit value OR\n  "
                    << "LengthUnit::toAbbreviation() needs to be updated to handle a new LengthUnit value\n";
                throw(StringException(oss.str()));
        }
    };
};
typedef LengthUnit::type LengthUnit_t;
const std::string LengthUnit::DimName("Length");
const DimensionType_t LengthUnit::DimType(DimensionType::Length);
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LengthUnit_t unit)
{
    os << "( " << LengthUnit::toAbbreviation(unit) << ")";
    return os;
};
```

this is my first time attempting to use an CRTP because I've never had that kind of boilerplate similarity before and the errors I'm getting are of the form

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LengthUnit’
  static typename T::type fromString(std::string unitString)
                          ^~~~~~~~~~
 note: forward declaration of ‘class LengthUnit’
 class LengthUnit : public DimensionUnit<LengthUnit>
       ^~~~~~~~~~
 error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class LengthUnit’
  static typename T::type fromAbbreviation(std::string unitString)
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 note: forward declaration of ‘class LengthUnit’
 class LengthUnit : public DimensionUnit<LengthUnit>
```

google seems to indicate I've got an infinite recursion problem, but I'm hoping there's a smallish change I could make to avoid it.

Comment: Can we reduce this to a [mre] please?

Comment: Inside `DimensionUnit<T>`, `T` is an incomplete type (a compiler hasn't yet seen full `T`), so you can't refer to anything inside `T` in function signatures. This is a standard CRTP problem. Try to use `auto` as a return type or use type traits to extract `type` from `T`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503372/no-member-named-xxx-in-a-simple-crtp-case/70503917#70503917) for type traits technique.

Answer (score 0):

what I ended up doing is inverting it... I declared
BaseLengthUnit class with the enum and the lengthInMeters() toString() and toAbbreviation() functions
BaseTimeUnit class with the enum and the timeInSeconds() toString() and toAbbreviation() functions
BaseAngleUnit class with the enum and the angleInDegrees(), toString() and toAbbreviation() functions
I declared the templated DimensionUnit subclass (templated on the parent class which is one of BaseLengthUnit, BaseTimeUnit, or BaseAngleUnit)

and then did

typedef DimensionUnit LengthUnit;
typedef LengthUnit::type LengthUnit_t;

typedef DimensionUnit TimeUnit;
typedef TimeUnit::type TimeUnit_t;

typedef DimensionUnit AngleUnit;
typedef AngleUnit::type AngleUnit_t;

and completely avoided the need to use the CRTP.

it was really weird though because I've never included the header file of a subclass in the header file of the parent class before and now I did it 3 different times (once each for LengthUnit.hpp TimeUnit.hpp and AngleUnit.hpp which declared the BaseLengthUnit BaseTimeUnit and BaseAngle unit classes respectively and then typedef'ed the LengthUnit TimeUnit and AngleUnit classes, where the .cpp files were named BaseLengthUnit.cpp BaseTimeUnit.cpp and BaseAngleUnit.cpp, the whole thing bucked my usual coding patterns)