# Reference or pointer to std::vector of incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector

As answered here: [How can an incomplete type be used as a template parameter to vector here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345193/how-can-an-incomplete-type-be-used-as-a-template-parameter-to-vector-here) usage of incomplete type as template argument when instantiating a template component can result in undefined behaviour. But does that rule hold true when we have only pointer/reference to template component with incomplete type as argument? Does the instatiation happen in this case too?

For example:

```
// SomeAlgoInterface.hpp

#include <vector> 

struct Result; // forward declaration

class SomeAlgoInterface
{
  public:

   virtual ~SomeAlgoInterface() = default; 

  public:

    // the following line is definitely OK, ...
    virtual void f1(const Result & result) = 0; 

    // ... but I'm not quite sure about the following one
    virtual void f2(const std::vector<Result> & results) = 0; 
};
```

In other words, is the code above valid or not?

Comment: According to the examples in [temp.inst]/4, this declaration doesn't cause instantiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration is correct, so long as you don't call `f2`.

The compiler doesn't need to know the internal of `Result` class if you don't call `f2`. There's no storage allocation in the declaration.

If some compilation unit call `f2`, you need to supply the complete type for `Result` class, or you need another reference parameter to call `f2`:

```
void another_f(SomeAlgoInterface& i, std::vector<Result>& results)
{
    i.f2(results);  
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that calling this requires instantiation if you still don't use anything in the class  , e.g. in your example if `i.f2` also accepted the vector by reference